# setOnFocusChangeListener in ListView item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

What I want to do is display actions in ActionBar, if item of ListView is selected.
So I create : 
answer_item.xml:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

<EditText   android:id="@+id/simple_answer_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            />
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/file_loaded_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

And AnswerAdapter class :

```
public class AnswerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Answer>{
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final Fragment parentFragment;
    public AnswerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,Fragment parentFragment) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        this.parentFragment = parentFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.answer = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simple_answer_item);
            holder.loadObjectImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_loaded_view);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final Answer answer = getItem(position);
        holder.answer.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "click " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (parentFragment != null && parentFragment instanceof onAnswerListItemFocusChange)
                        ((onAnswerListItemFocusChange) parentFragment).onListItemFocusChange(true, answer);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "unclick "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    final int position = view.getId();
                    final EditText answerBody = (EditText) view;
                    getItem(position).setBody(answerBody.getText().toString());
                    if (parentFragment != null && parentFragment instanceof onAnswerListItemFocusChange)
                         ((onAnswerListItemFocusChange) parentFragment).onListItemFocusChange(false,answer);
                    view.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        holder.answer.setText(answer.getBody());
        holder.answer.setId(position);


        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder{
        public EditText answer;
        public ImageView loadObjectImageView;

    }
}
```

Moreover I have android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" in ListView:

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bad_answer_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants">
        </ListView>
```

So when I run app and focused EditText at position for exmaple 2 in ListView , I expected to see only "click 2" but in result I get "click 2" "unclick 2" "click 0" "unclick0" "click2"
And becouse of that I think in my ActionBar I see only one action 
But normally in EditText not in ListView works fine and I see 3.

So please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can't you simply use onItemSelectedListener on the ListView? If you want to have the edittext somehow change it's color, too, then put duplicateParentState=true to it. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for answer, ok so I tried to do this but onItemSelectedListener is never call, if I select item from list I focus EditText and only onFocusChange in Adapter is call.

Comment: They probably override each other. Try disabling the focusmanager. You will handle focus by the other listener. Use duplicate parent state so that also the edit text changes its state

Comment: For test I set EditText attr:  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:clickable="true" android:focusable="false" But still onItemSelectedListener in not call. hmm

Comment: Remove focusable as well.. On item selected listener must work..

Comment: I dont know why, but onItemSelectedListener not work. I fight with it hours but still nothing.